# Lucene: searching for a particular group of consecutive words in a sentence

Tags: lucene

I have indexed a list of words such as 'just saw','just passed','just met'.. I have a list of sentences and I want to extract only those sentences which have these keywords in it. for eg
'I just saw a movie'. but I don't want the sentences which are like ' I was in US and met Obama'. I want only those sentences which have consecutive keywords. How can I do that using luence

Comment: Have you tried searching with a phrase, putting quotes around it: "just saw" "just passed"

Comment: I am passing a sentence 'I just saw a movie' ..And in my index there are keywords like 'just saw' .so I want this sentence to be selected.But if i pass 'I saw a movie' the result is true. I want the result to be true only if the sentence contains 'just saw' as consecutive words

Comment: Can you clarify? It sounds like you're saying: even if they search for "I was in US" you wouldn't want that to find anything because it doesn't contain "just ___"? (i.e. you want to filter your search criteria?)

Comment: @Xodarap: yes you are correct.. I have a list of keywords which are indexed. and when I am passing a sentence if it contains that keywords then only that statement i should get.

Answer (score 3):

[Proximity Search in Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_0_0/queryparsersyntax.html)

Lucene supports finding words are a within a specific distance away. To do a proximity search use the tilde, "~", symbol at the end of a Phrase. For example to search for a "apache" and "jakarta" within 10 words of each other in a document use the search:

```
"jakarta apache"~10
```

Comment: Hi aron,
I am passing a sentence as a search parameter instead of a word and my words are indexed. So I want the sentence to return true if the words 'just saw' are in the sentence but the words need to be consecutive words in the sentence eg "I just saw a movie" should return true and " I just has lunch and saw movie" should return false.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [SpanQuery](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/07/18/the-spanquery/) which gives good control over the order of the terms.

Comment: in the example they are passing single word as parameter for search. But I am passing sentence. and the words are indexed.